# why rep movb uses data segments?

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

If using the old segments registers is outdated why does still exist in the current days when I have like this:

```
rep movsb %ds:(%rsi),%es:(%rdi)
```

what is this "ds" and "es" doing? It wouldn't be the same without the segments?

Comment: Go ahead and omit the segments. The segment for `rsi` defaults to `ds` and the segment for `rdi` defaults to `es`, so you don't need to say it.

Comment: @RaymondChen not to mention that in 64 bit code that this clearly is, they are ignored anyway. That looks like the output from a silly disassembler that likes to show default segments and implicit operands.

Comment: objdump :/ and gdb also shows the segments...

Comment: The instruction is usually written as `rep movsb` that's all.

Comment: @Jester I think the segments are still respected for `fs` and `gs`, but yeah, `ds` and `es` are required to be flat, so there's no difference between them. (At least that's my reading of 7.3.9.4 "String operations in 64-bit mode.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to specify them, but they are still "there."  They are not being used as "Segment Registers", however; they are being used as selectors.

The segment registers are now used as selectors out of the Global Descriptor (or possibly local descriptor) table, which is used to define memory regions and their read/write permissions.

Comment: is like "asking" GDT if address that rdi or rsi has is available to write or whatever the instruction needs to do?

Comment: Mmm.. It's not asking, it's telling.  EDI will use the ES selector and ESI will use the DS selector.